# ScrollView in android

Tags: java, android

I have a TableLayout, in which rows are dynamically created, thus it may cross the limited screen size. To avoid this I am trying to add a scroll view after creating the table layout as:

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
tl.addView(sv);

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this); 
    .
    .
    .
    .  //finally iam adding this table row to layout.
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            SmsActivity.class);
            // setMessageBody((String) tvf.getContentDescription());
            // submit.setEnabled(false);
            String messageText = (String)  valueTV.getText();
            String dateText = (String) labelTV.getText();
            myIntent.putExtra("messageText",dateText+"\n"+message);

            startActivity(myIntent);
        }});
}
```

However the application is getting force closed if the number of rows increases more than the size of display.

My log cat shows the error as

```
06-28 14:41:49.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the TableLayout to the ScrollView, and not the other way around.

Comment: i've changed it as ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
  
  TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

  sv.addView(tl); but it still gets force closed and gives following error      06-28 15:11:11.013: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1465): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: @ramtej, that is because, the tablelayout is already inflated from the XML and has a parent to it, so you cant add that particular view to a scrollview, So modify your xml layout so that the table layout is a child of the scrollview

Comment: @ramtej: like Azlam said, include the ScrollView in the XML file instead of creating it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView can only have one child and will throw an IllegalStateException if you try to add more than one. Typical practice is a ScrollView with another view inside it containing the views over which you wish to scroll.

Having said that, you appear to be getting a different sort of IllegalStateException so I'm not 100% sure that this is the issue.

In my view, though, the real solution is to not dynamically populate a ScrollView but instead use a ListView, which is explicitly intended for just this sort of thing. It's a little more work but very rewarding in terms of performance and scalability.